# HP G62 Won't turn on after plugging in HDMI cable.

Tags: boot

I plugged in my Rocketfish HDMI cable (which was already connected to my TV) and boom, my computer turns off as if it was unplugged and the battery removed. This had also happened to me yesterday when I removed the cable, but my laptop started working again after I left it unplugged (with battery reomved) for the day.

I've tried removing the battery and unplugging the AC and removing static by holding down the power button, but nothing seems to have worked. When I plug in the AC Adapter the charging LED lights up. When I press the power button, theres a quick flash and its gone, also the charging LED stops.

I don't know what to do. I'm comfortable opening up small parts of the laptop (RAM area, HDD etc) so kinda difficult solutions are welcome. Any clues?

Comment: There was another question a little while back, where the individual was curious about whether or not devices should be turned off before connected via HDMI.  http://superuser.com/questions/421067/is-it-really-necessary-to-unplug-devices-from-the-wall-before-connecting-hdmi  as it turns out, manufacturers recommend that they are.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to HP's bad hardware design, but the solution is simple:

1. Unplug AC and remove battery for a few seconds
2. Reinstall battery and plug in AC
3. Plug in HDMI on both devices (laptop and TV) while they are turned off
4. Turn on your TV
5. Press HP power button and your laptop should boot up normally